# Msgpack error: msgpack::v1::insufficient_bytes

Tags: c++, zeromq, msgpack, publisher, subscriber

The publisher send a message.
Sending takes place via the zeroqm library. The message is sent via msgpack. A created string file is packed and sent. The puplisher works great and sends out the messages.

The Subscriber receives the data. Error occurs during unpack:
Compiling works without errors. The programme is interrupted during the run in the line: `msgpack::unpack(msg, static_cast<const char*>(got.data()), got.size());`

the error is: `msgpack::v1::insufficient_bytes`

**Publisher**

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include "zmq.hpp"
#include "zmq_addon.hpp"
#include<msgpack.hpp>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t ctx(1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher(ctx, zmq::socket_type::pub);

    std::stringstream ss;
    
    publisher.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5041");
    
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    std::string msg_str = "Test";

    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;

    
    msgpack::pack(sbuf, msg_str);

    zmq::message_t msg_send(sbuf.size());
    memcpy(msg_send.data(), sbuf.data(), sizeof(sbuf));
    
    
    while (true)
    {

        publisher.send(msg_send, zmq::send_flags::none);
        std::cout << "Mitteilung ist online: " << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        
    }

}
```

**Subscriber**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<zmq.h>
#include<zmq.hpp>
#include<msgpack.hpp>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t ctx(1);
    zmq::socket_t subscriber(ctx, zmq::socket_type::sub);

    subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5041");

    subscriber.set(zmq::sockopt::subscribe, "");
    
   


    while (1)
    {
        std::string um_str_;
        msgpack::unpacked msg;
        zmq::message_t got;
       
        subscriber.recv(got);
        msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

        std::cout << "Hier" << std::endl;

        msgpack::unpack(msg, static_cast<const char*>(got.data()), got.size());
       // obj.convert(um_str_);

    }


}
```

Comment: I recommend that checking hex dump started from `got.data()` to `got.size()`.
Then check the format https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Can you please describe your note in more detail? I thank you